# I want to sync mat-select value in my create.component.ts and actuator.component.ts in typescript, how can I sync them?

Tags: angular, typescript

this is my actuator files that have some rows. in each row is a edit button that when click on it open a dialog `create.component`
mat-select have three value and It should be change when one of them choose.

Actuator don`t have submit button but create have.

actuator.component.html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="timing">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> زمانبندی </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="dir-ltr">
                        <mat-label>زمانبندی</mat-label>
                        <mat-select (selectionChange)="timingSelectionChange($event)" matTooltip="تعیین نوع زمانبندی">
                            <mat-option value="automatic">خودکار</mat-option>
                            <mat-option value="manual">دستی</mat-option>
                            <mat-option value="periodic">دوره ای</mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
            </ng-container>
```

actuator.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.dataSource = new ActuatorDataSource(this.setService);
        this.totalCount$ = this.dataSource.totalCount$;
        if(this.organs[0]) {
            this.dataSource.loadActuators(this.organs[0].id, 'name', 'asc', 0, this.pageSizeDefault);
        }
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // reset the paginator after sorting
        this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);
        // on sort or paginate events, load a new page
        merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
        .pipe(
            tap(() => this.loadActuatorsPage(this.selectedOrgan))
        )
        .subscribe();
    }

    loadActuatorsPage(organId: string, sort: string = this.sort.active, direction: SortDirection = this.sort.direction, offset: number = this.paginator.pageIndex, count: number = this.paginator.pageSize) {
        if(this.dataSource) {
            this.dataSource.loadActuators(organId, sort, direction, offset, count);
        }
    }

loadActuators(organId: string, sort: string, sortDirection: SortDirection, pageIndex: number, pageSize: number) {
        this.loadingSubject.next(true);
        const actsObs = this.setService.getActuators(organId, sort, sortDirection, pageIndex, pageSize)
        .pipe(
            catchError(() => of({ data: [], count: 0 } as ResultCount<Actuator>)),
            finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false)),
        );
        this.actSub.unsubscribe();
        this.actSub = interval(30000).pipe(
            startWith(actsObs),
            switchMap(() => actsObs)).subscribe({
                next: (result: ResultCount<Actuator>) => {
                    const totalCount = result.count;
                    const actuators = result.data;
                    this.totalCountSubject.next(totalCount);
                    const data: TableElement[] = [];
                    for(const actuator of actuators) {
                        const sections = actuator.actuatorToSections.map((atos) => atos.section_id);
                        data.push(
                            {
                                id: actuator.id, name: actuator.name, organ_id: organId,
                                type: actuator.actuator_type.display_name, type_id: actuator.actuator_type_id,
                                application_id: actuator.application_id, application_name: actuator.application.name,
                                manual_state: actuator.manual_state, automatic_state: actuator.automatic_state, is_manual: actuator.is_manual,
                                state_timing: { value: "automatic", name: "خودکار" } /* actuator.state_timing */,
                                on_periodic: 50,
                                off_periodic: 2,
                                sections: sections
                            } as TableElement
                        );
                    }
                    this.actuatorsSubject.next(data);
                },
                error: (err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                }
            });
    }
```

create.component.html

```
<div>
                    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                        <mat-label>زمانبندی</mat-label>
                        <mat-select (selectionChange)="timingSelectionChange($event)" formControlName="state_timing">
                            <mat-option value="automatic">خودکار</mat-option>
                            <mat-option value="manual">دستی</mat-option>
                            <mat-option value="periodic">دوره ای</mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                    <mat-slide-toggle #manstate_toggle color="primary" formControlName="manual_state" matTooltip="وضعیت تنظیم شده توسط کاربر">
                        <span *ngIf="manualState?.value; else elseBlock">روشن</span>
                        <ng-template #elseBlock>خاموش</ng-template>
                    </mat-slide-toggle>
                </div>
```

create.component.ts

```
private createTableElement(id: string, body: ActuatorBody, automatic_state: boolean, state_timing: any) {
        const sections = body.sections.map((section) => section.number);
        return {
            id: id, name: body.name, organ_id: this.selectedOrgan,
            application_id: this.selectedApp.id, application_name: this.selectedApp.name,
            type_id: this.selectedType.id, type: this.selectedType.name,
            manual_state: body.manual_state ? body.manual_state : false, automatic_state: automatic_state, is_manual: body.is_manual ? body.is_manual : false,
            state_timing: { value: this.selectedTiming.value, name: this.selectedTiming.name },
            on_periodic: this.onPeriodic?.value,
            off_periodic: this.offPeriodic?.value,
            sections: sections
        } as TableElement;
    }

onSubmit(): void {
        const body: ActuatorBody = this.form.value;
        if(this.isEditForm()) {
            body.id = this.data.element?.id;
            if (this.isManual && this.manualState && !this.isManual.value) {
                body.manual_state = this.manualState.value;
            }
            this.setService.editActuator(body)
                .pipe(map(id => id.toString()), take(1))
                .subscribe({
                    next: (id: string) => {
                        const auto = (this.data.element) ? this.data.element.automatic_state : false;
                        const timing = this.data.element?.state_timing.value;
                        const result: DialogResult<TableElement> = { message: "تنظیمات ذخیره شد.", succeed: true, data: this.createTableElement(id, body,auto, timing) }
                        this.close(result);
                    },
                    error: (err) => {
                        console.error(err);
                        this.error$.next(err.message);
                    }
                });
        }
        else {
            this.setService.createActuator(body)
                .pipe(map(id => id.toString()), take(1))
                .subscribe({
                    next: (id: string) => {
                        const timing = this.data.element?.state_timing.value === "atoumatic";
                        const result: DialogResult<TableElement> = { message: "تنظیمات ذخیره شد.", succeed: true, data: this.createTableElement(id, body, false, timing) }
                        this.close(result);
                    },
                    error: (err) => {
                        console.error(err);
                        this.error$.next(err.message);
                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

I don`t know what can I do it for this part